# getting the index of a characterset in a string

Tags: iphone

i have to put UIImageView object at those places in my string where i have got special character.For that i have replaced those special characters with spaces so that i can put my imageView in that space.Now the problem is getting the x co-ordinate of the imageView.Remember i may have to many imageViews nd there indexex are dynamic.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Using UIImageViews is hardly an optimal solution. You might try using a UIWebView or do your own drawing (using Core Graphics or Core Text).

Comment: well, good luck with that. the only choice that comes to mind is using NSString's sizeWithFont additions, but that will be both expensive and unreliable with multiple lines.

Comment: why is a UIWebView no option? you can load it with data generated locally (use data: uri scheme for the images if you like), and you can disable user interaction. What problem would then be left?